# SImple NASM program to output first number in an array gives Segmentation Fault error

Tags: segmentation-fault, nasm

I'm trying to make a really simple NASM program that will output the first value in my array.

When I run it, I get a `Segmentation Fault`. I can't figure out why. The value in the array is a byte, and the length I am putting into the `edx` register is `1`. Why is there a fault?

```
segment .data
    array: db 2, 9, 6, 7, 1, 4

segment .bss

segment .text
    global main

main:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, [array]
    mov edx, 1
    int 0x80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're getting a seg fault because you're not ending the program correctly.  It is running into no man's land!

```
mov   eax, 1
xor    ebx, ebx
int     80H
```

is the proper way of exiting a program.  Also, your not printing what you expect.  those numbers in your array are not ASCII, you need to convert to ASCII in code, or just enclose in quotes.

```
array    db  "2", "9", "6", "7", "1", "4"
```

also, sys_write expects and address not a value, remove the brackets around array

*** EDIT ***

```
%define sys_exit    1
%define sys_write   4
%define stdout      1

section .data
array       db  "2", "9", "6", "7", "1", "4"

section .text
global main
main:
    mov     eax, sys_write
    mov     ebx, stdout
    mov     ecx, array
    mov     edx, 1
    int     80H

    mov     eax, sys_exit                
    xor     ebx, ebx                      
    int     80h
```

Comment: It works! But it prints out all the values. How do I print just one (i.e. the first)?